# Create security camera with ubuntu mate

Tags: security, ubuntu-mate, camera

How can I make security camera automatically start recording through cheese when I connect to device to the electricity? Ubuntu mate.
Thanks a lot!

P.s using eye toy camera that work only with cheese as far as I know..

Answer (score 1):

The package `motion`, which is in the repos, lets you set up a security camera system which can record continuously or only when motion is detected.

Further info can't be given unless you supply info about your setup, but `motion` works well for me with a very low-end USB camera.